# cfmail - An email address works in "to:" but doesn't work in "failto:"

Tags: coldfusion, smtp, coldfusion-9, smtpclient, coldfusion-10

I am having a problem with a specific email address. When I use that address in `to` attribute, it works and the email goes through. But when I put the same address in `failto` and try sending email to an address that doesn't exist, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Just to get it straight in my head, you ONLY get problems when to="invalid@invalid-domain.com" and failto="valid@valid-domain.com"? It may be worth getting the full stack trace of the error from the CF logs and posting that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My administrator found out it was the problem with the Mail Server. He changed the Mail Server and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

The `failto` attribute on `CFMail` sets the reverse-path on the mail envelope. Because of spamming concerns, [most mail servers check up on the email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) being used and disallow invalid ones, which may be what's happening to you. Take a look at this article for [how the Mail Server does it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_verification).